# Cursor is not rotating up to end of the Process in Windows Mobile Application

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a button in my Form and when I click the Button It will get the data from different tables through webservice.

I am writing the code below

```
private void imageButtonWorkOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        //Code for to get data from 10 tables
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;            
    }
}
```

But the problem I am facing is that the cursor is not rotating end of the process. It's simply stopping after some time.

Please suggest me how to fix this problem.

Thanks in Advance,
Balu

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to say based on what little we know.  One thing that could cause your behavior is that if this section of your code:

```
//Code for to get data from 10 tables
```

Ever sets the cursor back to Default, then it won't wait for your finally block.  Any Worker threads running could also change it back - the Cursor isn't per-thread, and it's not reference counted.

As a side observation, getting a bunch of data in a click handler - especially when it takes enough time to warrant a wait cursor is not a good practice.  Even if we don't look at separation  of concerns (which this code probably lacks), the entire UI is going to appear "locked up" to the user.  You're far better served to get the data in a background thread and signal the UI when it's done so it can do UI population at that point.